# How to force to open link in Safari from WebApp in iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, safari, uiwebview

There is a link like `<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>` inside a web page of `UIWebView` in my app.How can I force this link opened with Safari when it's clicked?I've tried `target="_blank"` as someone suggested, but not work.Does anyone know that?

And how about a `<form>`, how can I make it redirect to Safari when it's submitted?

It's better to approach this through `javascript`, but not `javascript objective-c interaction`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try following :

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_system');">Google</a>
```

This works in Phonegap.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work for me, looks like it needs `InAppBrowser` plug-in.